# What Is Wrong with This Boolean Variable Decleration and Usage in PL/SQL Code?

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, plsql, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile the following PL/SQL:

```
PROCEDURE SP(INPUT1 IN VARCHAR2)
  V_BOL BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
  IF (INPUT1 = 'XYZ')
    THEN V_BOL := TRUE;
  END IF;

  UPDATE T1 /* Line 17 */
  SET T1.C1 = (
    SELECT CASE
      WHEN (V_BOL AND T1.N1 BETWEEN 1 AND 10) THEN 'J' /* Line 20 */
      END
    FROM DUAL)
...
```

But getting the following error:

```
Error(17,9): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(20,18): PL/SQL: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

Comment: Replace the first line with `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP(INPUT1 IN VARCHAR2) IS`, but the line 17 and 20 cannot be seen. So, we need to see the rest.

Comment: You don't need a `select` for the assignment in the update statement. `SET T1.C1 = CASE WHEN (V_BOL AND T1.N1 BETWEEN 1 AND 10) THEN 'J' else null end` should do just fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `BOOLEAN` variables in SQL statements (unless Oracle changed that in recent releases), i.e. `**V_BOL**` is not valid.

```
UPDATE T1 SET T1.C1 = 
CASE WHEN (**V_BOL** AND T1.N1 BETWEEN 1 AND 10) THEN 'J' else null end
```

Use a simple SQL data type, i.e. INTEGER (0/1)

Comment: *sigh* You are right. Oracle SQL vs. PL/SQL. Thanks.